# XLib - How to correctly cancel the process of incremental data transfer?

Tags: c++, x11, xlib, xorg

I have read [this](https://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/) and looked for in many other places over the Internet, but I can't find the answer to my question. In a C++ program I have a class `Clipboard`. This class is monitoring X11 selection events and fetches the selection content into a string member when it changes. For large selections X11 uses the 'INCR transfer' mechanism. This process is described in the above link. When fetching the content of a large selection, I want to check if the selection size exceeds some limit(let's say, 20 megabytes), and if it does, I do not want this selection to be fetched to avoid inadequate memory consumption by my program. And this is roughly how I do this at the moment:

```
void Clipboard::fetchLargeSelectionContent()
{
    /* We have received a property of type 'INCR' and are now going to start
       the read process 
       Variables ending with '_' are class' private members */
    Atom clipboard = XInternAtom(display_, "CLIPBOARD", false);
    Atom target = XInternAtom(display_, "UTF8_STRING", false);
    unsigned long nItemsToRead = 0;
    Atom typeReturned = None;
    int formatReturned = 0;
    unsigned long nItemsReturned = 0;
    unsigned long nBytesRemaining = 0;
    unsigned char* dataReturned = nullptr;
    // We do not want selection to exceed 20 megabytes
    std::string::size_type sizeLimit = 20 * 1024 * 1024;
    bool maxSizeExceeded = false;
    // Listen for property events on the requestor's(us) window
    XSelectInput(display_, window_, PropertyChangeMask);
    /* The xlib::getCurrentTime() function is defined in a separate header file
       and returns the current X server time */
    Time propertyReadTime = xlib::getCurrentTime();
    /* Notify the selection owner that we are ready to receive the data
       by deleting the property of type 'INCR' */
    XDeleteProperty(display_, window_, property_);
    while (true)
    {
        XEvent event{};
        XNextEvent(display_, &event);
        if (event.type == PropertyNotify &&
                event.xproperty.state == PropertyNewValue &&
                event.xproperty.display == display_ &&
                event.xproperty.window == window_ &&
                event.xproperty.time >= propertyReadTime)
        {
            // Read zero bytes from the property just to get the size of its content
            XGetWindowProperty(
                    display_,
                    window_,
                    property_,
                    0,
                    0,
                    false,
                    target,
                    &typeReturned,
                    &formatReturned,
                    &nItemsReturned,
                    &nBytesRemaining,
                    &dataReturned);
            XFree(dataReturned);
            dataReturned = nullptr;
            if (nBytesRemaining == 0)
            {
                // Transfer completed
                XDeleteProperty(display_, window_, property_);
                break;
            }
            nItemsToRead = nBytesRemaining;
            propertyReadTime = xlib::getCurrentTime();
            // Read the content and delete the property requesting a new data chunk
            XGetWindowProperty(
                    display_,
                    window_,
                    property_,
                    0,
                    nItemsToRead,
                    true,
                    target,
                    &typeReturned,
                    &formatReturned,
                    &nItemsReturned,
                    &nBytesRemaining,
                    &dataReturned);
            if (!maxSizeExceeded)
            {
                content_ += std::string(
                        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(dataReturned),
                        nItemsReturned);
                maxSizeExceeded = content_.size() > sizeLimit;
            }
            XFree(dataReturned);
            dataReturned = nullptr;
        }
    }
    if (maxSizeExceeded)
    {
        content_.clear();
        std::string().swap(content_);
    }
    XSelectInput(display_, window_, NoEventMask);
}
```

This approach works, but there is an obvious downside with it - the data will still be received even after the `sizeLimit` has been exceeded, it just won't be written to `content_`. But why would I want to receive the data that I am not going to store and use? I need to somehow notify the selection owner that I am not interesting in receiving new data chunks anymore, and it should abort the INCR transfer process. But I have not found a way to do it. I've tried to simply replace `while (true)` with `while (!maxSizeExceeded)` to break the loop immediately after exceeding `sizeLimit`. But it seems that the selection owner is still waiting for my program to read the data it sent, because I can see significant growth of system memory usage with every consequent copy of 500MB text data. It doesn't happen if using the approach from my example though(read the entire data and just ignore it if it is too large in size).

So, the question is in the title - how to gracefully(correctly) abort the process of incremental data transfer, and is there even any way to do it?

Comment: It looks like  *2.3.1. Voluntarily Giving Up Selection Ownership* is your friend here?  I don't really know; I'm just reading the docs.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I don't want to change the owner of a selection. I just want to somehow tell the owner to stop sending me data and waiting for my response. Section 2.7.2 describes how to send/read data incrementally, but it is unclear is there any way to abort this process at some point without receiving all the data.

Comment: FWIW, I think what you're doing is correct. Any data-transfer protocol either does or does not have a cancel mechanism.  This one appears not to, so your only option is to complete the transfer by wasting the bytes.  I think it could be more efficient, though.  IIUC you're checking for the size on every chunk.  Can't you just check for the total size first, then enter a loop to fetch the data?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to predict the overall size of a selection, but I've moved the size check to `if(!maxSizeExceeded)` block(code edited), so that no more checks will be performed after it had already became known that the maximum size is exceeded. This is just an example code, but thank you for pointing this out! Anyway, even reading a really huge(hundreds of megabytes) selection seems to be a pretty fast operation if it doesn't follow by subsequent write(to string) operation, so I think I will just leave it as it is. Appreciate your participation.

Comment: X11 and Xlib are not a Linux-specific protocol/API, so why did you re-add the `linux` tag?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I'm sorry, in my opinion X11 and Xlib are closely related to Linux.

Comment: They're the same on any system, not even just Unix ones.

Comment: There were no responds to this topic, and I just thought that Linux audience are more likely to help me. This is why I added Linux tag.